# How to overcome "ValueError: Resolve param in estimatorParamMaps failed" PySpark error?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to save a grid-searched PySpark `TrainValidationSplitModel` object, and while tuning the regularization of the logistic regression I'm getting the following strange error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-8e6b86f1e92c> in <module>
      1 # Save model, or upload if already saved
      2 if not os.path.isdir(drive_path + 'lr_2_model'):
----> 3     lr_2_model.save(drive_path + 'lr_2_model')
      4 else:
      5     lr_2_model = TrainValidationSplitModel.load(drive_path + 'lr_2_model')

5 frames
/content/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in meta_estimator_transfer_param_maps_to_java(pyEstimator, pyParamMaps)
    324                         break
    325                 if javaParam is None:
--> 326                     raise ValueError("Resolve param in estimatorParamMaps failed: " + str(pyParam))
    327                 if isinstance(pyValue, Params) and hasattr(pyValue, "_to_java"):
    328                     javaValue = cast(JavaParams, pyValue)._to_java()

ValueError: Resolve param in estimatorParamMaps failed: LogisticRegression_87f4bc317e0b__regParam
```

This is the code that caused the error. This code worked with a previous `LogisticRegression` PySpark model where I tuned the `maxIter` parameter.

```
# Save model, or upload if already saved
if not os.path.isdir(drive_path + 'lr_2_model'):
    lr_2_model.save(drive_path + 'lr_2_model')
else:
    lr_2_model = TrainValidationSplitModel.load(drive_path + 'lr_2_model')
```

This is the code where I defined `lr_2_model` (`grid_search` is a custom function I wrote. The error can't be with that as it's been working with other models):

```
# Run grid search
%%time
if not os.path.isdir(drive_path + 'lr_2_model'):
    lr_2_model = grid_search(stages_with_classifier=lr_2_stages, 
                             train_df=train_df_preprocessed, 
                             model_grid=lr_2_grid, 
                             parallelism=5)
```

And this is the code where I defined `lr_2_grid`, `lr_2_stages`, and `lr_2`.

```
lr_2 = LogisticRegression(
    featuresCol='scaled_features',
    labelCol='Anomalous',
    weightCol='Weight',
    standardization=False)

lr_2_stages = stages + [lr_2]

# Specify parameter grid
lr_2_grid = ParamGridBuilder()\
            .addGrid(lr_1.regParam, list(np.linspace(0.001, 0.1, 5)))\
            .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I was calling a previous `LogisticRegression` model in my `ParamGridBuilder`:
`.addGrid(**lr_1**.regParam, list(np.linspace(0.001, 0.1, 5)))\`

*facepalm*